# Discard Ongoing Card for effect (Mad Mod)

Tags: dc-comics-deck-building

I'm playing the Teen Titan's version of the DC building game which focus heavily on "Ongoing" effect cards. Now we came across an scenario that we are not too sure on.

Now he plays the "Mad Mod" card, (for those of you who are not familiar this is what the card reads)

> +2 Power, You may discard an **ONGOING** card you control. If you do,choose a foe and **ATTACK**: That foe gaines a **WEAKNESS**

Lets say he has 4 ONGOING cards, which leads him to say that he discards all four and i get 4 weakness card. I was under the impression that you could only discard one, but he insist that since it doesn't say "Once Per turn" that he can discard multiple ones and keep activating the "attack" part. I have looked every where online but I have not found an answer to this. There are also other cards that read the same way that you may discard an "Ongoing" card and it does an effect. 
Can these be activated multiple times? or just once?

Answer (score 2):

From what I recall, Mad Mod is not an Ongoing card, so therefore the effect (+2 power, discard an Ongoing card for an attack) happens only once.  By his argument, you could also get 200 power.

Comment: Agreed. Unless a card explicitly states "for each" or "ONGOING", most cards are one-shots. If he plays multiple Mad Mod cards, though, then he can attack more than once and gain +2 power each time.

Answer (score 0):

It reads "an ongoing card," this is singular, therefore one card. "Teen Titans go" is a card that differs and says for each, also if it wasn't multiple the cost would be like 7/8 and I know it is not.